# Types of property 'imports' are incompatible when using routing

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

**app.routing.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule }   from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent }  from './components/login/login.component';
import { TestsComponent }  from './components/tests/tests.component';
import { NotFoundComponent }  from './components/notfound/notfound.component';
import { AppModule }  from './app.module';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'anmelden', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'tests', component: TestsComponent },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing: AppModule = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { routing,
         appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing';

import { AppComponent }  from './components/app/app.component';
import { LoginComponent }  from './components/login/login.component';
import { TestsComponent }  from './components/tests/tests.component';
import { NotFoundComponent }  from './components/notfound/notfound.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent, LoginComponent, TestsComponent, NotFoundComponent ],
  imports: [ BrowserModule, routing ],
  providers: [ appRoutingProviders ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**The result:**

[image]

Edit:
This errors only occurs when using *npm start*. If I delete the *imports:* row in the module run *npm start* and add this line again everything works fine.

Comment: I haven't upgraded to this router in Angular 2, but looking over the tutorial: It types that routing const as `export const routing: ModuleWithProviders`. You have it as `AppModule`.

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem! (It's imported from @angular/core)